# pass parameter from pipeline middleware to factory class in zend expressive 2

Tags: php, mezzio

I want to connect to different database according to URL. I try to set request attribute and get that attribute in `*Factory.php`.
I edit `autoload/pipeline.php`:

```
<?php
$app->pipe(UrlHelperMiddleware::class);
$app->pipe(\App\Action\Choose::class);
$app->pipeDispatchMiddleware();
```

in `Choose.php` I implement `process()` like this:

```
<?php
public function process(ServerRequestInterface $request, DelegateInterface $delegate)
{
    /** @var RouteResult $route */
    $route = $request->getAttribute(RouteResult::class);
    if ($route->getMatchedRouteName() == 'FirstRoute' or $route->getMatchedRouteName() == 'SecondRoute') {
        $request = $request->withAttribute('DB_NAME', $route->getMatchedParams()['param']);
    }
    return $delegate->process($request);
}
```

The main problem is in `*Factory.php` I don't access to request.
Any try to access to `Interop\Http\ServerMiddleware\MiddlewareInterface` or `Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface` in *Factory.php raises same error.

Is there any way pass parameter from pipeline middleware to factory class?

Answer (score 0):

If you use zend-servicemanager you can try this (just a theory, not tested):

Create 2 database factories in your config:

`'db.connection.a' => DbFactoryA::class,
'db.connection.b' => DbFactoryB::class,`

Then depending on the route, in `Choose` you load the connection you need and pass it to the container as the default connection.

`$db = $container->get('db.connection.a');
$container->setService('db.connection.default', $db);`

And now in all following middleware you can grab the default connection.

**UPDATE:**

As mentioned in the comments, this requires the container to be injected which is considered bad practice. How about you wrap the two in a common connection class and set the required from `Choose`:

```
class Connection
{
    private $connection;

    /**
     * @var ConnectionInterface
     */
    private $db_a;

    /**
     * @var ConnectionInterface
     */
    private $db_b;

    public function __construct(ConnectionInterface $a, ConnectionInterface $b)
    {
        $this->db_a = $a;
        $this->db_b = $b;
    }

    public function setConnection($connection)
    {
        if ($connection === 'a') {
            $this->connection = $this->db_a;
            return;
        }

        $this->connection = $this->db_b;
    }

    public function getConnection()
    {
        return $this->connection;
    }
}
```

Or you can inject only the config and create the database connection that's really needed. Store it in a property for caching (like the container does).

Comment: Thank you,But I think pipeline middleware(in this case:`Choose` class) `implements Interop\Http\ServerMiddleware\MiddlewareInterface` and in `process(ServerRequestInterface $request, DelegateInterface $delegate) `we don't access to `$container`.

Comment: You are right. It's bad practice to inject the container. But I think exceptions can be made for special use cases. After all, it is a sort of a factory since it needs to interact with the container. I don't see any other way how to do this.

Comment: @ooghry I've added another solution so you don't need to inject the entire container.

Comment: I appreciate your helping me, but if I have more than 5 connection or add new server to system, maintenance this code is hard.